# Qsort for a particular range in C?

Tags: c

I have to q sort an array but for a given range for ex.

```
Given array
4 5 3 7 2 1
```

and then i have the range 2 & 5 this means i have to sort from index 2 all the way through 5.

```
Resultant array
4 5 2 3 7 1
```

I know we can set one bound 
like

qsort(array,4,sizeof(int),compa)

this will sort the array till 3rd index but will always start from index 0. I want to start the first bound by a desired value. Any Suggestions??

Answer (score 6):

Just pass address to the middle of the array.

```
qsort(array + 2, 5 - 2, sizeof(int), compa);
```